получить тип generic в классе через рефлексию
есть generic классMyClass<T>
в другом классе я храню его как переменную
private MyClass<int32> _myClass1; private MyClass<string> _myClass2; (например)
теперь я через рефлексию получаю эти Field и мне необходимо узнать тип этого T (generic)

Обобщения у поля не может быть задано, оно может быть задано только у метода или класса. Несовсем понятно, что вы пытаетесь получить, покажите пример класса, кода получения и ожидаемый результат. Отредактируйте вопрос.

вроде постарался подробнее донести мысль,надеюсь будет понятно)

@Nidze Можете показать для каких целей вам это надо? Что то мне подсказывает, что всё это можно решить гораздо проще

Вы же в коде прямо написали тип, то есть если обращаться к _myClass1, то заведомо известно что будет string, верно? Нет никакого смысла здесь использовать рефлексию. К тому же рефлексия медленно работает.
